# React useEffect null ref when calling function directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

Why `myRef.current` is null when using a function directly inside `useEffect` instead of putting it inside an arrow function that is inside the `useRef` arguments.

This will not work and will throw a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

**Mycomponent**:

```
function Mycomponent(props){      
  let myRef = useRef(null);    
  useEffect(myFunction(myRef),[]);  
  return(
    SOME COMPONENT...
  );    
}
```

This will work:

```
function Mycomponent(props){      
  let myRef = useRef(null);    
  useEffect(()=>{ 
    myFunction(myRef);
  },[]);
  return(
    SOME COMPONENT...
  );    
}
```

Edited:

```
function myFunction(component){      
  component.current.addEventListener("click", handleClick);    
}
```

Comment: Post `myFunction` also.

Comment: Those are not interchangable. The first one immediately invokes `myFunction()` and the second one invokes `myFunction()` in the callback.